# How can I set program associations in mac?

Tags: macos, mac, file-extensions

I know the way to change association per extension (get info => open with => change all) but is there a way like in Windows to change association of all video extensions to be opened by VLC like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Just to clarify, are you asking specifically about doing this for VLC? Or, are you using VLC and the screenshot purely as examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With on-board GUI tools this isn't possible. But you can download and install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) which is a PrefPane.

Open System Preferences > Default Apps. Choose the Apps tab, scroll down to VLC in the left panel and choose it. In the right panel scroll down to Extensions and hit the (cycle) button...

[image]

This works for other apps too - VLC is just an example also used in the question!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024 and macOS 10.12+ the working solution is to use [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps)

If you are using Homebrew, it's one command away:

```
brew install swiftdefaultappsprefpane
```

and can be found in the bottom of System Settings list.

Answer (score -3):

You have to right-click on the file that you want to open, let's say it's and .avi, then go to info and then you should see a menu that says "open with" expand it and choose the software that you want to use to open that type of file format.